# Query about perforce integration of two codelines

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

i have two codelines A & B. I integrate my changes from A to B.

Now lets say i want to integrate file x.

x-1 has been already integrated to B.

Now in A i have made changes in X with X-2 and also to some other files (y1,y2) then reverted (backed out the whole CL) with x-3 alongwith y1,y2 files. so basically x-1 & x-3 is same.
Now i add one more change x-4.

Now if i have to integrate x-4 with the file in codeline B. Do i have to provide CLs of x-2 and x-3 ?

cheers,
Saurv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perforce it's more common to use "#" as the sign that separates the filename from the revision.
If I get you right, your scenario is:

```
A/x#1  (integrated to B/x#1)
A/x#2  (changes)
A/x#3  (rollback changes from #2 so #1 and #3 are identical)
A/x#4  (other changes)
```

Now in order to make B/x be identical to A/x#4 you can simply integrate the head-revision of A/x (including all changes made on A/x) to B:

```
p4 integrate A/x B/x
p4 resolve -as
p4 submit
```

You could also integrate just the diffs made in A/x#4:

```
p4 integrate A/x#4,4 B/x
```

But in the end that wouldn't make no difference except that perforce still thinks that you didn't integrate the diffs submitted with #2 and #3, so it wouldn't be wise.

Comment: thanks for the answer...also for letting me know the convention of denoting the file version